Not proper show 3d chart with type of the barchart in Highchart Angular 18
enter image description here
Version : "highcharts": "^11.4.7",
In this Below Code All another chart proper work but only 3d barchart not render proper, simple barchart also do proper work but when barchart swtich on the 3d bar chart then issue faces.
Same code work on the Older package Version and its work fine.
this.myChart = Highcharts.chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: "chartcontainer",
    type: "bar",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 15,
      beta: 15,
      depth: 50,
      axisLabelPosition: "auto",
      viewDistance: 25,
    },
    spacingTop: 10,
  },
  noData: {
    style: {
      fontWeight: "bold",
      fontSize: "15px",
    },
  },
  title: {
    text: this.chart_settings.title_setting.show_title
      ? !this.emptyChartData
        ? this.chart_settings.title_setting.title_name
        : " "
      : " ",
    style: {
      color: "#000000",
      fontWeight: "normal",
      fontSize: "24px",
      fontStyle: "none",
      textDecoration: "none",
      "font-family": "Roboto-Regular, sans-serif",
    },
    align: "center",
    verticalAlign: "top",
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true,
    itemStyle: {
      color: "#000000",
      cursor: "pointer",
      fontSize: "13px",
      textDecoration: "none",
      textOverflow: "ellipsis",
      fontWeight: "normal",
      fontStyle: "none",
      "font-family": "Roboto-Regular, sans-serif",
    },
    align: "center",
    verticalAlign: "bottom",
    alignColumns: false,
    navigation: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    symbolRadius: 100,
    symbolHeight: 12,
    symbolWidth: 12,
  },
  xAxis: {
    visible: true,
    gridLineColor: "#e6e6e6",
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    categories: ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"],
    crosshair: true,
    lineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: "#000000",
        cursor: "default",
        fontSize: "13px",
        fontWeight: "normal",
        fontStyle: "none",
        textDecoration: "none",
        "font-family": "Roboto-Regular, sans-serif",
      },
      format: "{value}",
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    visible: true,
    gridLineColor: "#e6e6e6",
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    reversedStacks: false,
    lineWidth: 0,
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: "",
    },
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: "#000000",
        cursor: "default",
        fontSize: "13px",
        fontWeight: "normal",
        fontStyle: "none",
        textDecoration: "none",
        "font-family": "Roboto-Regular, sans-serif",
      },
      format: "{value}",
    },
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      stacking: "normal", // If you're stacking bars
      pointPadding: 0, // Remove space between bars
      borderWidth: 0,
      depth: t25, // 3D depth for bars
      edgeColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.05)", // Edge color to enhance 3D visibility
      edgeWidth: 1, // Edge width to highlight 3D effect,
      groupZPadding: 40,
    },

    series: {
      animation: false,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
          fontSize: "13px",
          fontWeight: "normal",
          color: "#000000",
          textOutline: "none",
          textShadow: false,
          fontStyle: "none",
          textDecoration: "none",
          "font-family": "Roboto-Regular, sans-serif",
        },
        format: "{y}",
      },
    },
  },
  series: dataSeries,
})

How can do proper render barchart.

Can I share my console.log to you can find better way to missing property?

Can you give me what is the solutions for this?

Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example? You can start by editing this basic 3d-column example in Highcharts Angular: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-pkorb6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Bug Resolved, Issue is because when we used 3d bar chart then its animation so, my logic is that bar create image and show in the canvas so, Issue is generate image and load in the canvas the before the animation end.

Issue is because of the 3d Row Chart animation and during the animation html2Canvas image capture image and that image show in canvas that's why issue face so I have disable the animation then proper work
